# Deploy macOS devices with images for employees

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, disk-image

In our company, we would like to deploy MacBooks and other Apple devices (e.g. iMacs) via images and make them available to the employees so that we can provide all employees with a uniform system equipped with tools and programs as quickly as possible.

Is this possible in the macOS universe (if yes, how?) or are there licensing problems? The goal is not to have to manually set up every Macbook one by one.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) See if this provides you with the information you are looking for: https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204142

Comment: As long as you're using actual Apple hardware (and not Hackintoshes) there are no licensing problems in using images. In fact, it has traditional been easier than for example Windows, as there's no serial numbers and no activation for the operating system itself. I think you would get the best answers to this question if you tell a bit more about the number of devices, you need. I.e. a small shop with 5 Macs would probably look at something a bit more simple than a larger organisation with 100 Macs.

Comment: We are talking about 20 Macs. Maybe 30-40 next year. "Real" Apple hardware, no Hackintoshes in use. Is there a good tutorial for creating and deploying images on apple devices? @jksoegaard

Comment: What kind of Macs are we talking about? - Is it the current M1 Macs? - Or is it older Macs with Intel processor? If so, how old? (before T2 or after?)

Comment: Without M1 chips, just intel. But with T2 chip, release date between 2018-2019 @jksoegaard